# Android: how to make on swipeRefreshLayout harder to swipe down

Tags: android, swiperefreshlayout

By that I mean that I have a simple swipeRefreshLayout and I want when the user scroll down to much more difficult until the bar up completed and triger onRefresh method. Something like Gmail. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you just want **harder** to swipe down, you can modify `SwipeRefreshLayout` source, make your own SwipeRefreshLayout:

```
public class SwipeRefreshLayout extends ViewGroup {
    private static final long RETURN_TO_ORIGINAL_POSITION_TIMEOUT = 300;
    private static final float ACCELERATE_INTERPOLATION_FACTOR = 1.5f;
    private static final float DECELERATE_INTERPOLATION_FACTOR = 2f;
    private static final float PROGRESS_BAR_HEIGHT = 4;
    private static final float MAX_SWIPE_DISTANCE_FACTOR = .6f; 
    private static final int REFRESH_TRIGGER_DISTANCE = 120; \\ change this value
```

but if you want a bar come up on ActionBar just like Gmail, I recommend you not use `SwipeRefreshLayout` in support library, but use a library like [ActionBar-PullToRefresh](https://github.com/chrisbanes/ActionBar-PullToRefresh).

Comment: Oh thanks :D The library ActionBar-PullToRefresh is what I need :D :D